# Finding elements in an array other than given indices

Tags: matlab

I want to find the elements in an array which are not the given index elements. For example, given an array `A = [1 5 7 8]`, and index `ind = [2 3]`, the operation should return elements `[1 8]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a direct index vector:

```
B = A(setdiff(1:numel(A),ind));
```

Or throw away unneeded elements:

```
B = A;
B(ind) = [];
```

Or use logical indexing:

```
% either
B = A(~any(bsxfun(@eq,ind(:),1:numel(A)),1));
% or
B = A(all(bsxfun(@ne,ind(:),1:numel(A)),1));
```